# c# Listview not scrolling because it is off screen

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to make a windows phone app so far so good, except one really annoying issue I'm having, i've been researching this for days and tried everything I can think of.

My layout is this: I have

- 1 main parent grid, 3 children grids 1 left 1 middle 1 right,
- the left grid has a left margin of -480 so its not visible on the
  screen,
- the right margin has a right margin of -370 so its not visible on the
  screen,
- I'm using grid.projection so when I button is pressed the    left
  grid slides in

I used this guide http://depblog.weblogs.us/2013/07/22/facebook-like-settings-pane-windows-phone/

there is a listview in both the middle grid and the left grid, the middle listview scrolls the left one does not. if I remove only the -480 margin from  the left grid the left listview will scroll.
so my problem is as soon as the listview is off the screen it stops scrolling even when called back to view

please help,
thanks

this is a drawing of the grids I am describing
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5KZY.jpg

UPDATE**

if I make the margin of the left grid to 360 so it is over lapping the center grid the list scrolls when the view is on the center grid, but when I switch the view to the left grid it stops scrolling

Comment: Have you checked the grids are not overlapping among them?

Comment: If you set a background to test for instance is one of your grid over another grid?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid x:Name="MenuGrid" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas">
                        <Canvas.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="OpenAnimation">
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="300"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="canvas"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Name="CloseAnimation">
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.4" To="0"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetName="canvas"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </Canvas.Resources>
                        <Canvas x:Name="canvas">
                            <Grid Background="White"
                                  Margin="0 0 0 30"
                                  Height="800"
                                  Canvas.Left="-300">
                                <ListView x:Name="TestListView"
                                          Visibility="Visible"
                                          SelectionMode="Single"
                                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HomeListViewTemplate}"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
```

Can you try this. The ListView normally when it is main screen it takes the height of its parent control like grid. But when its out of view it doesn't have a definite height. Controls like ScrollViewer,Listview will not scroll unless they have fixed height. So try to set height in XAML or in code.